# How to change value of child element based on attribute of child and parent?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

given this xml file

```
<root>
 <event id="123">
     <option subID="1">English</option>
     <option subID="2">German</option>
     <option subID="3">French</option>
     <option subID="4">Spanish</option>
 </event>
</root>
```

How do I change the value of spanish to Japanese?

I have this linq query:

```
var nodeToEdit = xml.Descendants("event").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("subID") == "4");
```

and after doing some stuff with this query I use this one to change the value:

```
foreach(var item in nodeToEdit.Elements())
{
    var query = item.Descendants("option").Where(z => (string)z.Attribute("subID").Value == "4");
    foreach (var bla in query)
    {
        bla.Value = "Japanese"; // bla.Value = Spanish
    }
}
```

but when I debug I can see that my `query` has no results.

Comment: You sure your XML doesn't use namespaces?

Comment: `<event>` doesn't have `subID` attribute : `var nodeToEdit = xml.Descendants("event").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("subID") == "4");`

Answer (score 0):

If that is your actual code and XML then yes it won't work for more than one reason. This is one possible way to fix it :

```
//select <event> node by id attribute
var nodeToEdit = xml.Descendants("event")
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "123");
if(nodeToEdit != null)
{
    //select <option> node within current <event> by subID attribute
    var optionToEdit = nodeToEdit.Elements()
                                 .FirstOrDefault(z => (string)z.Attribute("subID") == "4");
    optionToEdit.Value = "Japanese";
}
```

Or, only if the following this still considered readable for you, you can do in one go :

```
//select <option> node based on id attribute of it's parent & subID attribute of it's own
var nodeToEdit = xml.Descendants("option")
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Parent.Attribute("id") == "123"
                                            &&
                                         (string)x.Attribute("subID") == "4"
                                   );
```